# Retry System Update Not Working

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates, ota-update, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I just bought a new Galaxy SII 4G Touch and was updating it to ICS and I lost connectivity while downloading the update. Now when I go to About Phone > Update Android, there is a button saying "Retry Download" but it does not do anything when I press it.

I tried rebooting & even wiped cache, in addition to checking for firmware update too (none found).

Any ideas?

Comment: Try checking the SD-Card. Chances are the "broken update" was stored there. If so, delete it (it's either unusable as it is incomplete) and try again. As a "very last ressort" (if you don't want to wait until it's offered again), you might try a factory reset -- but even that is no guarantee you will be offered the update immediately again.